# 20.10 XPS13 2in1 9310 - resuming from suspend after 30-ish seconds

Tags: suspend, laptop, xps, 20.10

I have installed 20.10 Groovy on my new XPS13 2in1 9310, And have been having consistent issues with the device waking from sleep on its own.

I had installed 20.04, then upgraded to 20.10 for the newer drivers and compatibility. (Not Dell repos, since they don't seem to have specific support for this device yet, maybe I'm wrong)

Allow with that I had `Yubikey_Luks` configured and was having issues with suspending. I cleared out `Yubikey_Luks` to try and get it working again, but the device kept waking about 30 seconds after sleep.

I now have done a clean install of 20.10 and I am having the same issue:

Issue:

1. Closing lid, Selecting "Suspend" in Gnome search, or `systemctl suspend` in the terminal.
2. Device suspends/sleeps as you would expect.
3. After about 30 seconds, the screen wakes up (showing the lock screen)
4. The screen then goes dark and doesn't seem to suspend (pressing a key *immediately* brings up the lock screen, faster than normal wake-from-sleep).

I have searched forums and such for an answer to this issue and haven't found anything that quite covers this issue.

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this waking? Or how I can narrow down the problem?
(*Sorry for using suspend and sleep interchangeably, I mean suspend in all cases*)

Comment: Look at the logs! Read `man journalctl`, e.g. `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`.